# Expected times of dice rolls for sum of them to be $S_n \mod 7= 0$.

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, stochastic-calculus, markov-process, dice

**Exercise:**

> What is the expected number of dice rolls until the sum of the rolls is a multiple of $7$ ?

**Attempt:**

Let $S_n$ be the sum of the results of $n$-roll dices and $T_k = \inf\left\{ k >0 : S_k \; \text{multiple of 7}\right\}$.

Let's assume the Markov Chain $S'_n = S_n\mod 7$ and then it will be $T'_k = \inf\left\{ k \geq 1 : S'_k = 0\right\}$.

Since we are interested in the expected value $\mathbb E \left[T'_k\right | S'_k = x]$, I know that we have to work with $g(x) = \mathbb E \left[T'_k\right | S'_k = x]$ where $g(x)$ is a solution to the problem $Lg(x) = -1$ and then find $g(0)$, but I am having a hardtime constructing the state space and understanding the modeling of the problem.

I would really appreciate any thogough explanation as Stochastic processes isn't really my field.

Comment: What is $L{}{}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition $T_k=\inf\left\{k\ge0:S_n\;\text{multiple of 7}\right\}$ doesn't make any sense. $k$ is a free variable on the left and a bound variable on the right; $n$ and $k$ are not related; and if you allow $k=0$ the infimum is trivially $0$. So I’ll make three changes to it and assume that you meant $T=\inf\left\{k\gt0:S_k\;\text{multiple of 7}\right\}$.

If so, you don’t need a Markov chain for this problem. On every roll except the first roll, if the experiment has not ended yet, you have probability $\frac16$ of reaching a sum $\equiv0\bmod7$. Thus the expected number of rolls beyond the first is geometrically distributed with parameter $\frac16$, and the expected total number of rolls is $1+\frac1{\frac16}=7$.

Comment: I apologise, the $\geq$ and $n$ instead of $k$ were typos. Okay, I understand this given approach via probabilities. If instead we wanted to work with a Markov Chain, by theory I know that we want to model a problem that solves $Lg(x) = 1$. $L$ is an operator, such that: $$\sum_{y \in \mathbb X} p(x,y)(g(y) - g(x)) = -1.$$ Even in that case, though, I am struggling to find out what the state space should be and how are the probabilities $p(x,y)$ calculated. Since $g(x) = \mathbb E \left[T'_k\right | S'_k = x]$ then finding $g(0)$ via the method above would yield the solution.

Comment: @Rebellos: Sorry, I can't follow you. You write "$L$ is an operator, such that", followed by an equation that doesn't contain $L$. I would recommend to take more care checking what you write.

Comment: $Lg(x) = \sum_{y \in \mathbb X} p(x,y)(g(y) - g(x)) = - 1$.